# How do I plot a logarithmic function and a normal one in the same graph(2D)

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

It's a really simple question. I want to plot x^2 and the log of x^2 in the same graph. I'm really new to Mathematica so I'm sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: Try this: `Plot[{x^2, Log[x^2]}, {x, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: I propose to close this question as off-topic, since it is based on the lack of trivial knowledge of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := Log[x^2];
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]